# Java: reading a variable number of bits and converting to an integer

Tags: java, bit, bytebuffer

I need to write a method which reads a variable number of bits from a *Byte*Buffer and converts those bytes into a primitive `int` or `long` (if more than 32 bits). I am not very proficient at working with bits, but I did look at some code examples and answers to similar(ish) questions and here is the best that I could come up with (`bb` refers to an internal `ByteBuffer`):

```
    public int readBits(int number) {
        int initialPosition = bb.position();
        int value = 0;
        int remaining = number;
        int position = bb.position();
        while (remaining > 0) {
            int index = (position >> 3);
            int bit = (position & 7);
            int bitsLeft = Math.min(8 - bit, remaining);
            int nibble = (bb.get(index) >> (bit & BIT_MASKS[bitsLeft]));
            value |= nibble << (number - remaining);
            position += bitsLeft;
            remaining -= bitsLeft;
        }
        bb.position(initialPosition + ((position - initialPosition) >> 3));
        return value;
    }
```

The `BIT_MASKS` array is defined as following:

```
    private static final int[] BIT_MASKS = new int[] { 0, 0x1, 0x3, 0x7, 0xf, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff };
```

I tested this method using this test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int nm = 4;
    BitSet bs = new BitSet(nm);
    bs.set(2);
    bs.set(3);
    BitBuffer bb = new BitBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(bs.toByteArray()));
    System.out.println(bb.readBits(nm));
}
```

I expected a value of 6, but it prints 12 and I'm not sure why.

I would appreciate some help with this. Thanks.

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: I haven't ran this through a debugger. I usually debug by just printing out messages or numbers at certain points in the code to see where it goes wrong, but I'm not quite sure where to start here.

Comment: Yeah, you start by using a debugger.  This is exactly what they're for.  I'm sure you'll find the problem in less than two minutes if you try.