# Blocking input to a Canvas using a JLayer

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt, jlayer

I am trying to write code which utilizes a `JLayer` to block events from going to the component being decorated by the layer. However, I can't figure out a way to do it.

[Here is a SSCCE](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=c2UcLbR4). It is a *pastebin* link because the code insertion always butchers the formatting when I try to use it.

```
public class Window extends JFrame{

    private static boolean blockInput = true;
    private CustomCanvas canvas = new CustomCanvas();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Window().setVisible(true);
    }

    public Window() {
    canvas.addMouseListener(canvas);
    LayerUI<Canvas> layerUI = new CanvasLayerUI();
    JLayer<Canvas> canvasLayer = new JLayer<Canvas>(canvas, layerUI);
    add(canvasLayer);
    setSize(800, 600);
    }

    private class CanvasLayerUI extends LayerUI<Canvas> {

    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e, JLayer<? extends Canvas> l) {
        if (blockInput) {
        if (e instanceof InputEvent) {
            ((InputEvent) e).consume();
        }
        } else {
        super.eventDispatched(e, l);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);
        if (c instanceof JLayer) {
        JLayer<?> layer = (JLayer<?>) c;
        layer.setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends Canvas> l) {
        super.processMouseEvent(e, l);
        if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
        System.out.println("Mouse click on layer: " + e.getPoint());
        }
    }
    }

    private class CustomCanvas extends Canvas implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mouse click on canvas: " + e.getPoint());
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
    }
}
```

I did some searching for examples of developers trying to do exactly what I am doing, and the best answer that I found was one of the last posts on [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2268000?tstart=0). Basically, the suggestion was to consume the `InputEvent` in the `eventDispatched` method in `LayerUI`. In my example, I tried doing that (when the `blockInput` flag is set to `true`), but it does not block the input from going to the `Canvas` - the `"Mouse clicked on canvas"...` message is still printed. However, `"Mouse clicked on layer"...` is not printed, so consuming the event only seems to block events from being processed within the `JLayer`, but I need them to not go to the `Canvas`. As a desperate attempt, I also tried to consume the `MouseEvent` within `processMouseEvent` with no luck.

I fear that the problem may be because `Canvas` is an AWT component, not a light-weight Swing component. Unfortunately, it is imperative that it is an AWT `Canvas` for the application that I am writing.

Has anyone managed to get block input events from going to the heavy-weight component decorated by the `JLayer`?

Comment: To format, select the code block and click the braces icon. Is that a `java.awt.Canvas` your extending? As an aside, consider `MouseAdapter`.

Comment: Yes, it is a `java.awt.Canvas`, and the reason why I'm not using a `MouseAdapter` is because I plan to implement all mouse listener methods, I was just displaying some test code I had. Also, when I use the code block, it just "flattens" my indentations and I have to manually put in four spaces to indent the code so it looks correct, and that's a pain in the butt.

Comment: I'll be happy to edit the code into the question, if you like.

Comment: `It is a pastebin link because the code insertion always butchers the formatting when I try to use it.` why don't you have problems in your other questions? For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530554/java-reading-a-variable-number-of-bits-and-converting-to-an-integer.  I've posted code with either all spaces or all tabs and it works fine. Fix the code to be consistent and you won't have a problem.

Comment: I manually indented the code with four spaces in the other questions because I usually only post a few lines.

Comment: @MartinTuskevicius, `I manually indented the code with four spaces` - Why would you do that? I just 1) copied the code from pastebin 2) pasted the code 3) selected all the code, and 4) clicked on the "{ }" button and the forum adds the 4 spaces for you. Why would the process work for me (and trashgod) but not for you?

Answer (score 1):

Your layer seems to work with a `JComponent`, such as `JPanel`. See also [*Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) and [*How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html).

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame {

    private boolean blockInput = true;
    private CustomPanel panel = new CustomPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MyWindow().setVisible(true);
        });

    }

    public MyWindow() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        LayerUI<JPanel> layerUI = new CanvasLayerUI();
        JLayer<JPanel> canvasLayer = new JLayer<>(panel, layerUI);
        add(canvasLayer);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private class CanvasLayerUI extends LayerUI<JPanel> {

        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e, JLayer<? extends JPanel> l) {
            if (blockInput) {
                if (e instanceof InputEvent) {
                    ((InputEvent) e).consume();
                }
            } else {
                super.eventDispatched(e, l);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void installUI(JComponent c) {
            super.installUI(c);
            if (c instanceof JLayer) {
                JLayer<?> layer = (JLayer<?>) c;
                layer.setLayerEventMask(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer<? extends JPanel> l) {
            super.processMouseEvent(e, l);
            if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
                System.out.println("Mouse click on layer: " + e.getPoint());
            }
        }
    }

    private class CustomPanel extends JPanel {

        public CustomPanel() {
            this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Mouse click on canvas: " + e.getPoint());
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(640, 480);
        }
    }
}
```